# Organize Downloads Folder

Tags: macos, organizer-software

Am looking for a script/application to organize my Downloads folder into different directories depending on say type of file and the day when it's downloaded. The folder grows huge after a week or so and I have to move the files myself. Will be great if I can just run a script and it does this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it yourself (you can execute scripts whenever a folder's contents change, it's called [Folder Actions](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/folderactions.html)). You can execute arbitrary (shell/Python/Perl/...) scripts using a simple AppleScript wrapper. You can even use [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)) to write simple scripts. [Here](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/) are some additional Automator extensions.

Alternatively, try [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php).

Comment: Like Hazel. But I think will write my own script sometime in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote mine eventually. https://github.com/a85/File-Sorter/blob/master/sort.py

Comment: Most of that is part of Finder's UI in OS X Lion (grouping by file types, and creating a folder with selected items). While not automatic, it's still easy to do.

Comment: I guess. I never found out. I use Windows, Linux and OS X together, so this works for me best. :)